# STM32F103RB Nucleo - no PLL multiplicator?

Tags: stm32, pll, stm32f10x, nucleo

I am using HAL to set up the core clock. When I add `RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = *any RCC_PLL_MUL*;` to my `SystemClock_Config` function, it appears that HAL_IncTick is never called so it cannot even pass the clock configuration stage. 
Now I am able to get only 8 MHz with `SYSCLKSource` HSI or HSE, and 16 MHz from PLL.
How to get the advertised 72 MHz clock frequency? Here is my init function:

```
static void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
    RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;
    RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;

    __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

    RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
//  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL9;
    HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct);

    RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = (RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1 | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2);
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;  
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;  
    HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0);
    SystemCoreClockUpdate();

    if (HAL_GetREVID() == 0x1001)
        __HAL_FLASH_PREFETCH_BUFFER_ENABLE();
}
```

Comment: If you download this example package: [STM32CubeF1](http://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32cubef1.html) the following example could help:
`STM32Cube_FW_F1_V1.4.0\Projects\STM32F103RB-Nucleo\Examples\RCC\RCC_ClockConfig\Src`

Comment: Thanks! It helped - following the example I changed `PLLMUL` when `SYSCLKSource` was set to HSI, and afterwards changed it to HSE. However, I cannot find an explanation in datasheets why it works like that. Could you please suggest me some good information source to read about that?

Comment: Well the reference manual should provide all the information to program the system clock on register level. Unfortunately HAL is not well documented. You could use STM32CubeMX tool for HAL code generation.

Comment: The CubeMX software is the best for this sort of thing or download the excel sheet. The cubemx software can generate code (HAL) which you can pare down if you don't use HAL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. HSE 72MHz

`    void SystemClock_Config(void)
    {

```
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEPredivValue = RCC_HSE_PREDIV_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL9;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

    /**Configure the Systick interrupt time 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

    /**Configure the Systick 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}`
```

2. HSI 64MHz

`

```
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL16;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

    /**Configure the Systick interrupt time 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

    /**Configure the Systick 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}
```

`